# Retrieving PHP JSON Array from Bundle in Swift Xcode Alamofire

Tags: php, ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am having a little trouble with pulling some JSON data from my test PHP Script. Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
   $testUsr = "test";
   $testPass = "pass";

   $return = array("usr"=>$testUsr,"pwd"=>$testPass);
   echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

This is the Swift Alamofire Request I am using (Swift Package):

```
AF.request(url!, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in
        if response != nil {
            print(response)
        }
        
        else {
            print("Error!")
        }
 }
```

When I use the above code, I get this error:

> failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))

However this error goes away if I use `.responseData` instead, and output as NSString, **but** this outputs the entire PHP Script in the console...

Any help would be much appreciated!

(Xcode 11/12, Swift Package Tools 5.3, iOS 13)

Comment: "Invalid value around character 0" error occurred when the json is invalid. Please first check the json in any platform like postman or any Rest client.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it wasn't a PHP or Swift Error - you cannot use POST for a locally sourced and referenced PHP Script, which I did not know!